# How to postion a pixmap in QT Designer

Tags: c++, qt

```cpp
void Editor::DisplayImage(QString(pathOfImage)) 
{
//    QPixmap pix (pathOfImage);
//    ui->lbl_DisplayImage->setPixmap(pix);
//    ui->lbl_DisplayImage->lower();

//    annotationPixmap = QPixmap(pix.size());
//    annotationPixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);

    ui->lbl_DisplayImage->setPixmap(annotationPixmap);
    annotationPixmap = QPixmap(pathOfImage);

    clickMouse = false;
}
```

I am trying to move this pixmap and change the size of the pixmap image. I have tried using labels but they prevent me from drawing over the images and the drawings are always placed behind the image.
Is there a way to manipulate the pixmap?

[image: QT Designer Window]

Comment: In the future please refrain from posting screenshots of your code, instead copy it into the question body with appropriate formatting

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is, but do you mean you want to change the stacking order of QLabel Widgets? Anyway, if you have complex image composition, you might want to use custom QWidget and override the paint event so you can draw exactly what you want. Or use QGraphicsView stuff, maybe.